# Where is mgconsole history file located?

Tags: memgraphdb

In Memgraph Lab I can see all of the old queries. Where can I see similar thing when using `mgconsole`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location for history file is `~/.memgraph`. At least so I see it on my Linux box.